# How to add a project-test.jar to a package?

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

For our test servers, we want to package our tests in a debian. In sbt, I can generate the test-jar using:

```
publishArtifact in Test := true
```

I've looked into using `member in Universal` and `addArtifact()` but I am having trouble finding a solution.

How do I add the test-jar into the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options.

#### Add to mappings

This is very simply done with this small snippet you can add to your `build.sbt`

```
mappings in Universal += {
  // generates the test package
  val testjar = (packageBin in Test).value
  // maps this file to your lib folder in your output package
  testjar -> s"lib/${testjar.getName}"
}
```

#### Add it to publishTask

This will generate the test package and publishes it, too. But it won't be added to the debian package.

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.SettingsHelper
SettingsHelper.addPackage(Debian, packageBin in Test, "jar")
```